# How do I access a specific category of documents across libraries by clicking a web part tile?

Tags: content-editor-web-part, modern-document-library

Wondering if there's a way to accomplish this task:

I've created separate categorized SharePoint libraries (i.e., Legal, HR, Business, etc.) which contain documents with a column-view based on specific subcategories associated with an internal department id (i.e., invoice, template, campus recruiting, etc.)

What I'd like to do is when a user clicks on a specific web part tile I'd like for all documents to be displayed tied to that specific column-view category regardless of what library the document is housed in.

For example:  User clicks on web part tile titled "Campus Recruiting" and all documents wherein the column value is "campus recruiting" are displayed regardless of the library they're housed in.

I am a bit of a newbie to SharePoint and would appreciate anyone advising whether this is possible and if so, how do I accomplish it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways of achieving it. 
1. Use content query web part. You can make a specific query across you site(s) to display specific content.

2. Use search. You can make the tile a link to to the search page with specific query that would display documents in your category.